# How to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space at Scala compilation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory-management, sbt, scalatra-sbt

I have noticed a strange behavior of my scala compiler. It occasionally throws an OutOfMemoryError when compiling a class. Here's the error message:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/gruetter/Workspaces/scala/helloscala/target/scala-2.9.0/test-classes...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

It only happens once in a while and the error is usually not thrown on the subsequent compile run. I use Scala 2.9.0 and compile via SBT.

Does anybody have a clue as to what might be the cause for this error? Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: The answers here also work for `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` (the equivalent problem for Scala running on Java 8) if you replace `MaxPermSize` with `MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The cause for `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` is that it doesn't have enough [permanent generation space](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/01/understanding-javas-perm-gen-maxpermsize-heap-space-etc.html) :) If you are using Oracle JVM, you need to add the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M` (or some other amount of space) argument to your `sbt` script. For other JVMs, look at their documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I've already used the -Xmx512M option. I think that should have the same effect, right? I've added the -XX:MaxPermSize parameter nonetheless and see if the error persists.

Comment: @BumbleGee No, memory added by `-Xmx` can't be used for PermGen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Alex.

Comment: It looks like a memory leak in SBT as the program compiles and runs sucessfully for about 3-5 times before throwing the exception which is fixed by SBT restart.

Comment: For the current version of `sbt` you need `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=256M` instead of `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M`. Tvaroh's answer is more accurate and complete, plus it doesn't make fun of the question.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a memory leak in either sbt or your application.  Wouldn't increasing permgen space only postpone the problem, not solve it?

Answer (score 100):

I use HomeBrew to install sbt on OS X. It supports a `SBT_OPTS` argument which can be put in `~/.sbtconfig` file with `export SBT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256M`.

Comment: Homebrew seems to be a very manageable package solution when developing with SBT. :)

Comment: the sbt brew install script sets memory max too small, get rid of the -Xmx512M in the java part - cat `which sbt`
#!/bin/sh
test -f ~/.sbtconfig && . ~/.sbtconfig
exec java -Xmx512M ${SBT_OPTS} -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.1/libexec/sbt-launch.jar "$@"

Comment: there's a good SBT_OPTS setting in http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html

Comment: worked for me on windows set SBT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=512M

Comment: `Use of ~/.sbtconfig is deprecated, please migrate global settings to /usr/local/etc/sbtopts`, 
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0`

Answer (score 38):

I assumed you're using **sbt** 0.13.6 or higher. Create `.sbtopts` file in your **sbt** project's root with the following content:

```
-J-Xmx4G
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

`MaxMetaspaceSize` is for Java 8 whereas `MaxPermSize` is for Java 7. They are critical to prevent out of memory errors related either to *permgen* or *metaspace* exhaustion. Of course, consider adapting flag values or adding any other flags required.

More details and alternative approaches can be found in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@jan______/sbtconfig-is-deprecated-650d6ff10236).

Comment: Great. You can also put these options in your global configuration file; for me it's `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` (for sbt installed with Homebrew on Mac).

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue, played around with it for 10 minutes looking at sites trying to change the memory size.

Turns out i resolved it by,

```
user-profile$ sbt
```

Then,

```
sbt-project-name 0.1> clean
```

This cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a memory leak in SBT for me as in my case the program compiles and runs successfully for about 3-5 times before hitting the exception which is fixed by SBT restart.

The most adequate solution indeed seems to be `-XX:MaxPermSize=` JVM parameter as Alexey Romanov suggests or to restart SBT periodically if it helps.

But there is another interesting way: try switching to [Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html). AFAIK it doesn't use PermGen any more and is probably immune to this exception this way.

I still hope SBT authors will address this issue in future versions.

Comment: So Java 8 uses a different memory system?

Comment: In J8 the perm gen is just rolled into the memory heap spaces.

Comment: With Java 8 SBT fails to compile, at least on my Mac. I have to downgrade to Java 7.

Comment: Perhaps you are doing something wrong, @C.R. As far as I can remember I have tried it with Java 8 on Linux that time (when it was in deep beta) with no visible problems ans am using it with Java 8 on Windows right now. Perhaps you could show us the compiler error message you get?

Comment: Thanks for the offer to help, but I decided not to go through the complicated process again. I'll stick to Java 7 for the time being.

Comment: Nope, I get a Metaspace OutOfMemoryError with Java 8, which is basically the same thing. The `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M` option fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

I am building with the Jenkins sbt plugin and had the same problems. They were resolved after copying the SBT_OPTS from the sbt file to the Jenkins job config's JVM flags.

Answer (score 3):

Originally using a command like:

```
java -jar /path/to/sbt-launch.jar test
```

I got first OutOfMemoryError: **PermGen space** which I solved using `-XX:MaxPermSize`, and then OutOfMemoryError: **Java heap space**, to which `-Xmx` was the remedy.

So in my case, a command like this worked:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx2048M -jar /path/to/sbt-launch.jar test
```

Answer (score 0):

change following code block in sbt.sh file and save its working fine.

```
get_mem_opts () {
  local mem=${1:-1536}
  local perm=$(( $mem / 4 ))
  (( $perm > 256 )) || perm=1024 //256 to 1024
  (( $perm < 1024 )) || perm=2048 // 1024 to 2048
  local codecache=$(( $perm / 2 ))

  echo "-Xms${mem}m -Xmx${mem}m -XX:MaxPermSize=${perm}m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=${codecache}m"
}
```

**or**

using terminal to export sbt config

```
export SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a `.jvmopts` file in the root folder of your project, and write inside the file the following:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx4g
```