# How to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am frequently getting an `OutOfMemoryError` from SBT.

```
> test
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
> last
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] Initially invalidated: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] Initially invalidated: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework' not present.
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: Stream((org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure,false,org.specs2.runner.Fingerprints$$anon$1@34d6488c), ?)
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: Stream()
[debug] Running Test ExpandoObjectTest : subclass(false, org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure) with arguments
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:196)
    at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:85)
    at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:88)
    at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:68)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:162)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:177)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$4.apply(Aggregation.scala:46)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$4.apply(Aggregation.scala:44)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:137)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasksWithResult(Aggregation.scala:44)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:59)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:31)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:30)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:90)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.State$$anon$2.process(State.scala:170)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:64)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:53)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:13)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sbt.Project$$anon$5.apply(Project.scala:130)
    at sbt.Project$$anon$5.apply(Project.scala:128)
    at sbt.LogManager$.commandBase$1(LogManager.scala:59)
    at sbt.LogManager$.command$1(LogManager.scala:60)
    at sbt.LogManager$$anonfun$suppressedMessage$1.apply(LogManager.scala:61)
    at sbt.LogManager$$anonfun$suppressedMessage$1.apply(LogManager.scala:61)
    at sbt.ConsoleLogger.trace(ConsoleLogger.scala:163)
    at sbt.AbstractLogger.log(Logger.scala:32)
    at sbt.MultiLogger$$anonfun$dispatch$1.apply(MultiLogger.scala:40)
    at sbt.MultiLogger$$anonfun$dispatch$1.apply(MultiLogger.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
    at sbt.MultiLogger.dispatch(MultiLogger.scala:38)
    at sbt.MultiLogger.trace(MultiLogger.scala:30)
    at sbt.TestLogger$$anon$2.trace(TestReportListener.scala:71)
    at sbt.TestLogger.endGroup(TestReportListener.scala:88)
    at sbt.TestRunner$$anonfun$run$5.apply(TestFramework.scala:87)
    at sbt.TestRunner$$anonfun$run$5.apply(TestFramework.scala:87)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$safeForeach$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:112)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$safeForeach$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Sometimes it also exits abruptly with:

```
sbt appears to be exiting abnormally.
  The log file for this session is at /var/folders/vf/3khb58091wd0_1rz1yh6knb00000gp/T/sbt3242766352271599341.log
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You don't say which version of SBT you're using, but early versions were very prone to running out of PermGen after just a few reloads of the project definition. Current versions seem fairly immune to this problem, but you might still just need to increase the allocation.

Comment: @RandallSchulz, the version is 0.12.2.

Comment: Also mention Java version and OS.

Comment: @SSR, 1.7.0_10 and OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29318498/312708 for the solution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This sometimes happens if you compile huge codebases - a lot of classes get loaded into the VM running sbt.

You need to increase the `PermGen` space for sbt - use the flag `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`, where `256` you can change with the desired size of the permanent generation.

Run:

```
cat `which sbt`
```

to locate you sbt startup script. Then edit it to include the flag with the `java` command that runs the sbt launcher in the similar way as it is [described here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html) for modifying `-Xmx` and `-Xms`.

Adding the `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` flag should also enable sbt to unload the classloaders with classes from the previous compilation runs that are no longer being used.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can set these options in the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable if you are using the [extended script for running sbt](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt).

Comment: Can you also set this using the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable?

Comment: I believe this depends on the SBT runner script you are using - if you use this extension script for running SBT, it should pick up the SBT_OPTS variable settings and allow doing much more: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some people, they have to use SBT_OPTS.  Please could you edit your answer to mention this, it caused my colleague a lot of pain. (then I will upvote :)

Comment: thank you - this helped. Typesafe activator was not working since the OSX brew install set a default max memory in sbt too small. edited the linked script in the Cellar with the SBT_OPTS in the "described here" link above. works well now

Comment: in manjaro linux the sbt script is in /usr/bin/sbt & I configed the line like so:  java $SBT_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=1200m   -jar /usr/share/java/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"