# compiler-interface not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3

Tags: scala

run sbt test in scala directory and get back:

```
[info] Set current project to bob (in build file:/Users/jonathanbarker/exercism/scala/bob/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jon/exercism/scala/bob/}bob...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10/2.0/scalatest_2.10-2.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10;2.0!scalatest_2.10.jar (541ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jon/exercism/scala/bob/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3. Compiling...
sbt appears to be exiting abnormally.
  The log file for this session is at /var/folders/dj/vxbs91y521z71sn3dkg_nsxm0000gn/T/sbt3697381862840689026.log
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Jonathans-MacBook-Air-1786:bob jon$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryError from SBT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957183/outofmemoryerror-from-sbt)

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957183/outofmemoryerror-from-sbt