# Intellij OutOfMemoryError: PermGenSpace with Scala

Tags: java, scala, sbt

and yes before you mark this as duplicate I've already read

[How to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957183/how-to-prevent-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

and

[How to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space at Scala compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331135/how-to-prevent-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-at-scala-compilation)

But it does not provide any solution to me.

**Here is the Problem**

I do have a simple test in my application written with junit like:

```
public class FooTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
    ...
    //Some Asserts
    ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this test with Intellij by simple click on "Run":

The following configuration is then created:

[image: Intellij Test Configuration]

Running the test prints then following:

```
[IJ][pos] $ all {file:/C:/somepath/test/}pos/foopackage {file:/C:/somepath/test/}pos/test:foopackage
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 6 Java sources to C:\somepath\test\target\scala-2.11\classes...
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:188)
        at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:83)
        at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:86)
        at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:66)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.liftedTree1$1(EvaluateTask.scala:359)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:358)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:378)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:64)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:62)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:314)
        at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:62)
        at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:71)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:32)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:31)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:153)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:152)
        at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:244)
        at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:241)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
        at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[IJ][pos] $
[IJ][pos] $
```

**Here is what I tried so far:**

As I mentioned Questions already posted I tried to get rid of this error by configuring the installed sbt on my system:

The version of sbt I installed is currently 0.13.15

So I configured the:

> C:\installpath\Scala\sbt_0_13_15\conf\sbtconfig.txt

like below:

```
-Xmx2G
-Xms2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-Dsbt.log.format=false
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

But I still got the same error. So I checked where Intellij is getting sbt from and if the build with `sbt test` from console would also fail.

> sbt test

Seems to run successful:

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 450 Scala sources and 1132 Java sources to C:\somepath\test\target\scala-2.11\classes
[info] Weaving 1 input to C:\somepath\test\target\scala-2.11\aspectj\classes...
[info] Compiling 103 Java sources to C:\somepath\test\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
[info] Instrumenting 6228 classes to C:\somepath\test\target\scala-2.11\jacoco\instrumented-classes
...
[info] 2 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
... And goes on and on
```

So I did check how it it configured in Intellij:

[image: sbt Configuration]

where as VM Parameters there I also typed in:

> -Xmx2G -Xms2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -Dsbt.log.format=false -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

But still I got the same error.

Then I tried adding a `.sbtopts` file into the roots folder.

The content of the file is:

```
-J-Xmx2G
-J-Xms2G
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-J-XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

After removing

```
-J-XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

from the `.sbtopts`- File in the projects folder it was possible to build the project.

It seems that this exception cam up:

```
C:\Java7\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:53488,suspend=n,server=y -Xdebug -server -Xmx2G -Xms2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Didea.managed=true -jar C:\installpath\Scala\sbt_0_13_15\bin\sbt-launch.jar idea-shell
Unrecognized option: -XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: It might be worth updating to Java 8 as Java 7 is no longer support. NOTE: Java 8 doesn't have a perm gen and most likely wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing

```
-J-XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

from the `.sbtopts`- File in the projects folder it was possible to build the project.

It seems that this exception cam up:

```
C:\Java7\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:53488,suspend=n,server=y -Xdebug -server -Xmx2G -Xms2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Didea.managed=true -jar C:\installpath\Scala\sbt_0_13_15\bin\sbt-launch.jar idea-shell
Unrecognized option: -XX+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: The flag must be spelled like this: `-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` -- note the colon after `XX`.