# Scala [2.11.6] Compile Stackoverflow error (appears resistant to advice found thus far)

Tags: scala, compilation, stack-overflow

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

I have of course tried `clean` many times as well as `update` -- unsure if there is a `clean-deeper` to refresh the jar (libraries).

What is really bizarre is that this occurred on TWO machines at the same time and one recovered without doing anything special and the other still has not. I've move up the code (about 2 weeks worth of effort) on the second machine thinking it was just some freaky luck of the draw type anomaly but sadly no.

If I can't fix this I'm terrified! How do you get work done when things will not compile?

Here is the head of the beast - it seems at times to be random - I need to record more than a few snapshots to be sure. The tail appears to be similar all the time but where the head starts seems to wander a bit.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:533)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(URLClassPath.java:758)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:843)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:199)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:364)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeErrorHandler(Namers.scala:111)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1542)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Namers.scala:781)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Namers$Namer$$logAndValidate(Namers.scala:1568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:772)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.completeImpl(Namers.scala:1684)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter$class.complete(Namers.scala:1692)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.complete(Namers.scala:1682)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1633)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5005)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3046)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2381)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4810)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4522)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
```

Aha! I was right - head of beast on next attempt

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:367)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:71)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2589)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1366)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:367)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:71)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1345)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
```

And head of the beast on yet another compile attempt -- so it appears to be somewhat indeterminate indicating that perhaps it is in fact memory related after all. (Most stack overflows are likely to be logic related not and in fact memory...)

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1366)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:367)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:71)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1345)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.mayNeedProtectedAccessor$1(SuperAccessors.scala:186)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transformSelect$1(SuperAccessors.scala:332)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:335)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAccessors.scala:71)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1372)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
```

Have tried the memory tricks.

[How to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space at Scala compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331135/how-to-prevent-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-at-scala-compilation)

My file is here: /Users/garyhewett/Applications/conf/sbtopts

And tried here: /.sbtopts as per:

[How to set heap size for sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt)

Have seen things like this: https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/issues/8 (indicating it's "not my problem" and yet it actually is now...)

Here are the current `.sbtopt` (in project root) contents

```
-J-Xmx2G
-J-Xss2G
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

It appears that even 2GB of Stack Space don't seem to help the situation (although I would like some way to confirm this file is even being read)

So help! (Please...)

Comment: The problem is stack, not heap, increase -Xss

Comment: -Xss2G doesn't appear to be enough so I'm not sure it is stack but also unsure if I'm telling it to increase the stack properly. Have added my `.sbtopts` file to the question for review.

Comment: Does your launcher script read sbtopts. Mine doesn't

Comment: I do not know. If I knew how to find out I would have found out by now. I am using `activator-1.3.5-minimal/activator` f that helps.

Comment: Ah - `-v` is very helpful! # Executing command line:
java
-Dactivator.home=/activator-1.3.5-minimal
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=64m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-jar
/activator-1.3.5-minimal/activator-launch-1.3.5.jar
~run

Comment: Success! `# Executing command line:
java
-Dactivator.home=/activator-1.3.5-minimal
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=64m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-Xss515m
-jar
/activator-1.3.5-minimal/activator-launch-1.3.5.jar
~run`
Had to put the `-Xss515m` on the command line that called activator.

Comment: Ironically as I move development to AWS Cloud9 it seems I'm right back to where I started. .sbtopts in the root of the project appears to be read but even on a 4 gig (T2.medium EC2 instance) I still can't find the magical incantation that gets a compile through. Of course this is the first link in Google so go figure...

Comment: Seems that -Xss515m on the command line is the ticket this time as well. I now have a compile! Glad I took the time to document that.