# How are sbtopts set for Typesafe activator [1.3.5]

Tags: java, scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I recently asked this question out of necessity ([Scala [2.11.6] Compile Stackoverflow error (appears resistant to advice found thus far)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801052/scala-2-11-6-compile-stackoverflow-error-appears-resistant-to-advice-found-th)) and finally managed to get something to work based on advice given.

*(Yes I will go back and answer that question properly myself but this question may help me provide a better answer)*

I'm not fond of hacking things together as I would much prefer to fully understand the various options available and make intelligent choices based on the power of expanded knowledge.

So this current question is specifically related to the typesafe activator platform and what specific ways and means are available for sending `options` to the underlying `sbt` portion of the platform?

*Brief pros and cons are OK for each if you feel so inclined however I do not want to make this a "what is the **best** choice" debate but merely a list of the main places one can inject `options` for the JVM and the SBT environment if/when necessary to deal with specific workload challenges.*

My situation saw me have to resort to using the command line itself as all the other routes I came across did not appear to have any effect (after I found the `-v` switch and could verify the parameters being called to run the JVM).

Hence this question :)